# RXJS Map Operator - Null Params

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am writing a pipe in angular.  I have this working on other pages, but for some reason, on this one, the map() (or maybe pipe()) operator is not working for me.  The parameter is null for some reason.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Project } from '../services/project/project.service';
/**
 * Project Status Filter Pipe.
 * Filters Projects by Status
 ** Usage: "Projects$ | statusFilter$:filter | async"
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'statusFilter$'
})
export class StatusFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items$: BehaviorSubject<Project[]>, ...args: number[]) {
    if (items$ === null) { return null; }

    const filter = args[0] || null;

    if (filter === null) { return items$; }

    console.log('status 1', items$); // Behavior Subject - value is array[36]
    return items$.pipe(map(
      items => {
        console.log('status 2', items);  // items is NULL
        items.filter(p => p.statusId === filter); //throws error
      }));
  }

}
```

This is how it is called:

`<ng-container *ngIf="(projects$ | statusFilter$: status.statusId  | async) as projects; else projectsLoading">`

and here is the code for loading projects$ which is called from ngOnInit() event:

```
private async loadProjects() {
    const projects = await this.projectService.listReport('organizations', this.orgId).toPromise();
    if (projects) {
      projects.sort((a, b) => {
        return (a.sortOrder > b.sortOrder) ? 1 : -1;
      });
    }
    this.projects$.next(projects);

  }
```

It throws the error on items.filter() since items is null.  Where are my 36 items going?

Comment: I doubt this is an issue with your pipe. Instead it is an issue with your behaviorsubject

Comment: what happens if you filter out null values before the map? ie `pipe( filter(f => !!f), map...)`

Comment: If you used braces {} you need to explicitly add return inside the map()

Comment: try return items$.pipe(map(items => { return { items.filter(p => p.statusId === filter)}; }));

Comment: Try to understand that the *value* passed to the `map()` operator comes from the observables. It has nothing to do with anything in your `StatusFilterPipe` because the observable is a passed parameter. So if you're getting an error inside the map function you should look where you created the observable.

Comment: Can you add the code where you use this pipe?

Comment: I added some of the usage information.  I think it probably is in the calling or loading because that would explain why it seems to work elsewhere in the app.

Comment: Try moving your

    this.projects$.next(projects);

into the if (projects) block otherwise your behavior subject will emit undefined.

Comment: It does the same thing if I move it into the  if (projects) block.

Comment: Are you calling `this.projects$.next` or `loadProjects()` multiple times or in multiple places? Could you the code of all the places where you call these functions. Also adding the complete console log output to your question would help to understand how often your Pipe is called and in with which input in which order.